# Why ViewChildren doesn't work with dynamic component?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Im searching for ways to insert values to a Dynamic Component using ngComponentOutlet. My last try before ask here was:

in the parentComponent.html:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="getButtonComponent()"></ng-container>
```

and in the parentComponent.ts

```
@ViewChildren(ButtonComponent, { read: ViewContainerRef}) list: QueryList<ButtonComponent>;
```

and the list is empty, it shouldn't be right?
It's should be a workaround for getting and setting a component created dynamically